# Dynamically explode list columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dynamic

I have a list of dictionaries which has been converted into a dataframe using `json_normalize`.

**Dataset:**

```
x = [{ 
    "_id" : 71, 
    "Ids" : [
        "10", 
        "59"
    ], 
    "roles" : [
        "janitor", "mechanic", "technician"
    ]
}]
```

**Dataframe:**

```
   _id       Ids                            roles
    71  [10, 59]  [janitor, mechanic, technician]
```

What I am trying to do is find a way to dynamically explode all the list columns/keys (Ids and roles) without explicitly typing the column names. Is this possible?

**Desired Output:**

```
   _id       Ids         roles
    71        10       janitor
    71        10      mechanic
    71        10    technician
    71        59       janitor
    71        59      mechanic
    71        59    technician
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the efficiency of this, but it just iterating over the dataframe column names and check whether it is `list` or not. If it is `list` just `explode`.

```py
df_final = df.copy()

for c in df.columns:
    if(isinstance(df[c][0],list)):
        df_final = df_final.explode(c)
```

```
    _id Ids roles
0   71  10  janitor
0   71  10  mechanic
0   71  10  technician
0   71  59  janitor
0   71  59  mechanic
0   71  59  technician
```

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution iterating through all entries checking for lists.

Works for multiple lines of entries and nested lists.

```py
    while True:
        newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
        for row in df.values:
            for index, value in enumerate(row):
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    for listentry in value:
                        newdf.loc[len(newdf)] = [*row[:index], listentry, *row[index+1:]] 
                    break
            else:
                newdf.loc[len(newdf)] = row
        df = newdf.copy(deep=True)
        if not newdf.applymap(lambda value:isinstance(value, list)).values.any():
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
from itertools import product

list_ = [df.iloc[0,i] if type(df.iloc[0,i]) == list else [df.iloc[0,i]] for i in range(df.shape[1])]
prod = list(product(*list_))
df = pd.DataFrame(prod, columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: I assume because there are ways to go about it without importing anything, and `df.iloc[0,2]` is assuming that there is a third column, it should be completely dynamic in the sense that the code should check whether a column contains a list, so it shouldn't assume there will always be 3 columns as it can vary each time

Comment: @mdbuzzer Thanks for your comment, now you have the independence for the number of columns